# dart_frog backend with database like hive or objectbox

Tags: database, dart, hive, backend, objectbox

I'm using [dart_frog](https://pub.dev/packages/dart_frog) package as backend. I need database, so can I use [hive](https://pub.dev/packages/hive) or [objectbox](https://pub.dev/packages/objectbox) as database.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: ObjectBox also works for Dart-only projects, so I don't see why not. See https://docs.objectbox.io/getting-started